# YouTube player cannot be built and keeps throwing error

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use the `YouTube` player [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube) in my React Native `TypeScript` mobile app but it's throwing an error and I cannot figure out how to fix this issue. I have researched a lot and installed some packages such as `deprecated-react-native-prop-types` and `metro-react-native-babel-preset` but still no luck.

In the Google Cloud Platform, I have enabled the `YouTube Embedded Player API` product in my project and created an API Key in it.

I'm running my application locally on the Android Studio Emulator and is using all the latest packages. Would that have anything to do with it?

My Code:

```
<YouTube
    apiKey = "API KEY HERE"
    videoId = "KVZ-P-ZI6W4"
    play = {true}
    fullscreen = {false}
    loop = {false}
    onReady={(e): void => { console.log(e); }}
    onChangeState={(): void => { console.log(); }}
    onChangeQuality={(): void => { console.log(); }}
    onError={(e): void => { console.log(e); }}
    style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 300 }}
/>
```

Error object return on `onError`:

```
{"error": "SERVICE_MISSING", "target": 235}
```

Error popup:

```
Get YouTube app:

This app won't run without the YouTube App, which is missing from your device.
```

Comment: Error exists in react-native-youtube source code, it needs to be fixed by editting source. You may try the temporary solution [here](https://github.com/davidohayon669/react-native-youtube/issues/539#issuecomment-1185174029).

Comment: @kiuQ I think version `2.0.0` is not supported by `TypeScript`. Is that true? Is there another way to get it working for `TypeScript` app?

Comment: I mainly develop app with js with `react-native-youtube`, so I don't really sure thats true or not. But I think it should support `TypeScript`.

Comment: If you are developing in Android and the error above, I think you are using Android 11 or newer OS to develop. That is a common error, you need to add `<queries> <intent> <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START"/> </intent> </queries>` in your `AndroidManifest` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android, I had to add the following code to the `AndroidManifest.xml`. For IOS, so far it's working on my `iPhone 6s Plus` device without any special change.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Other information:

Android Device: `Pixel 5 - API 31`
`react-native`: `0.71.8`
`react-native-youtube`: `^2.0.2`
`typescript`: `^5.0.4`